# Do we get new governor limits in test classes for each test method?

Tags: apex, unit-test, governorlimits

Do the governor limits refresh for each testMethod or we just get specific governor limits for each test class (for instance - SOQL limits 100+100 for test.start/stop)?

Please don't tag best practices to avoid SOQL 101 in test classes to this post, I am aware about those.

Answer (score 3):

It's a little more complicated than just saying you have a limit of, say, 100 queries. You have two governor limits. The moment a unit test starts, you have your testing governor limits. They are always the same as synchronous governor limits (e.g. 10,000 ms CPU, 6,000,000 bytes heap, 100 queries, etc).

When you call Test.startTest, those limits are suspended, and the very next statement you execute after that will set new governor limits. This may be synchronous limits (e.g. you call a controller), or it might be asynchronous limits (e.g. because you called System.enqueueJob). This is further compounded by the fact that you may have installed packages, which each also have their own limits (except for some shared limits, like CPU).

Once you call Test.stopTest, the limits that were used after Test.startTest are discarded, and the suspended limits become active once again. If you used 20 queries before Test.startTest, then you now have 80 queries remaining.

There's one wrinkle to this, though. If you use @testSetup, then those limits are used as part of the testing limits. For example, if you use 5 queries in a @testSetup method, then each unit test will be limited to only 95 additional queries. In order to avoid this behavior, it is imperative that you use Test.startTest at the beginning of your @testSetup method.

Each unit test is a separate transaction, and does get its own set of governor limits. This lets you have, for example, 100 unit tests in a class that each perform 100 queries (10,000 total queries!).

You'll want to do some profiling so you can optimize your organization's transactions, as failures in unit tests are often canaries in a coalmine. You should not assume that it's just the test is poorly written.

Comment: Not sure if it is a miss from Salesforce side but if we do Test.startTest and Test.stopTest inside @testSetup methods, we get total of three sets of governor limits.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they reset for each method and even within `startTest` and `stopTest` calls. Keep in mind that limits in a `testsetup` method are aggregated with limits outside of the `startTest` and `stopTest` calls, so you in effect have 2 sets of limits for each test.

You can get information about how test methods work [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_tools_start_stop_test.htm)

Sfdcfox (who else) has a more comprehensive answer [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/120791/clarify-the-governor-limits-with-test-starttest-and-test-stoptest/120797)

> When you run a unit test, Test.startTest() "sets aside" the testing governor limits, and creates a new set of limits based on the next line of execution. For example, if the next line of code is a DML operation, it sets up a normal trigger execution governor limit, while if it's a Database.exectuteBatch method, it sets the governor limits to the Batchable limits instead.
>
> So, you should definitely see two sets of limits, the former for the queries run outside of Test.startTest() and Test.stopTest(), and those inside. It's possible that since you didn't actually "do" anything inside the actual test phase, you may have caused some sort of bug, but ordinarily, you'd expect to see 99 "outside" queries and 1 "inside" query.
>
> Calling Test.startTest() doesn't "wipe out" the other limits, it only temporarily suspends them.

Comment: Thank you samir and sebastian for replying so fast. All the explanations I just read make sense to me but I still feel my question isn't answered or I am just not understanding it completely.
I'll keep it clear, let's take SOQL limits example again, I know I can use 100+100 queries with the help of test.start/stop in a test class with one test method. But can I use 400 queries (2x (100+100)) with 2 test methods in a single test class?

Comment: Technically yes, though you won't be able to share the results of those queries between methods.

I'd caution against using them all, though

Comment: Can you explain how that works? Since test.start/stop only suspends the limits, how do we get another 100 soql to use with the second testMethod?

Comment: I don't know *how* the back-end works, I know (based on documentation and real-life experience) that they just do. I am curious now, why do you need this information?

Comment: Did you read the first paragraph I quoted in my answer?

Comment: The reason behind asking this is we face a lot of SOQL 101 errors in our test classes lately and the reason behind it is that we do a lot of things inside one test class. So to save us from these errors I am trying to split code. With this question I am trying to understand whether I should divide code among different testMethods inside same test class or do I need to create new test class to split the code. Does that make sense?
before you suggest it we do use all other best practices like seeAllData,testvisible 
 variables,test.start/stop.

Comment: I read everything you added.

Comment: Split into methods inside the same class. You will be fine. I've done this before to good success.

Comment: Great!! Thank you Sebastian for your time.

Comment: You're welcome, and welcome to SFSE. Is it common practice (but not mandatory in any way) to upvote and/or accept answers that helped you solve your problem. Hope to you see you around!

Comment: I did upvote your answer but my reputation won't let you see it.

Comment: No worries at all, Shaleen.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. They reset for each method. However you can also use `test.startTest()` and `test.StopTest()` in your test method to reset the governor limit. Whatever put inside this mehtods will have a fresh set of governor limits